# Sass undefined method 'encode' for Array in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sass, sinatra

I'm trying to use sass with my Sinatra website, but I'm getting an error when it tries to convert the file:

undefined method `encode' for []:Array

```
get '/css/:stylesheet.css' do |stylesheet|
  content_type 'text/css', charset: 'utf-8'
  sass :"css/#{stylesheet}" # this is the line that crashes
end
```

the array is marked as empty because the file I'm requesting (site.css) is empty, if I put content in the file, the array has an object Id.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: 'the array is marked as empty' - which array are you referring to?

Comment: I assume it is an array used by the sass function as it has absolutely nothing to do with my code.
The problem was solved by using a more recent version of sass :)

Comment: If your problem was solved, then provide an answer.  Questions without answers show up in the "unanswered" questions listing.